# Why this :$I(x)=\int_{-x}^x {0.5(\exp({-t² {\operatorname{erf}(t^2)}})}dt$ is not error function for $|x| >3$?

Tags: probability-distributions, error-function

This integral : $$I(x)=\int_{-x}^x {0.5(\exp({-t² {\operatorname{erf}(t^2)}})}dt$$ close to $x$ for $|x|<3$ and converge to $1$ for $|x|>3$  from $-\infty \to +\infty$  as shown [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral(++0.5exp(-x%5E2+erf(x%C2%B2)+)),+x%3D-+infty+to+infty) such that concide with error function for that large range over Real number , Now my question here is it possible to consider  that distribution as  Gausse distribution for $|x|>3$ since there is a concidence ?

Comment: What does $|x| <-3$ mean?

Comment: sorry i meant 3